# use configuration we get from create-react-app or create our own custom webpack and babel configuration and install react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Which would be a better option when developing large React Applications ? Using the create-react-app and the default webpack and babel configurations provided by it or creating a custom webpack and babel configurations and install react packages ?

I have developed small applications in react using create-react-app and now wants understand every small part starting from webpack and babel. Do big companies use webpack and babel or simply create-react app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use create-react-app and as soon as you feel like yo need  to modify these files you do it. Create-react-app is a good way to start and those files can be edited whenever you need to!

Comment: can you give a better comparision between the two like advantages and disadvantages of using.

Comment: Basically the only disadvantage I see in create react app id that it will he instaling modules that you might not be using (such as unit testing). Otherwise I feel like the best way is using create react app to start, do the basic things you will use in your projects and save that project as a template for others.